# Missing case for deleting last node of sll

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure, singly-linked-list

So I'm learning how to work with linnked lists and I'm trying to write a function to delete the last node of a singly linked list.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *link;
} Node;

typedef struct List {
    Node* head;
    int number_of_nodes;
} List;
void list_delete_rear(List* list)
{
    Node *temp, *prev;
    temp=list->head;

        prev=temp;
        while(temp->link!=NULL)
        {
            prev=temp;
            temp=temp->link;
        }
        prev->link=NULL;
}
```

This works fine when there are more than one elements in the list. But when there is only one element, it doesn't get deleted. 
Sample output:

```
//printing original list elements:
102 101 100
//printing after using the function two times
102
//after using the function again
102
```

I am sorry if this question sounds really naive but i literally cannot understand what is going wrong. At this point it is so frustrating i would not even mind a few down votes as long as i can figure out what the problem is

Comment: Did you try debugging this code?

Comment: Probably you wish to change this `while(temp->link!=NULL)` to `while(temp != NULL)` as earlier one didn't traverse till last node.

Comment: Software development is 20% design, 10% coding and 70% test and debug...

Comment: @Achal that does not delete anything at all then

Comment: @bobthebuilder you need to debug it then. Use `gdb`.

Comment: Its some error in the logic, not the syntax. Debugging doesn't help

Comment: Syntax errors will not get past the compiler.  Debugging is all about logic errors!!

Answer (score 0):

Need double indirection

```
void list_delete_rear(List* list)
{
    Node **temp;
    if (!list->head) return;

    // Get pointer to pointer to last node
    for (temp=&list->head; temp[0]->next; temp=&temp[0]->next)
        ;

    // Free node pointed to by temp
    free(temp[0]);

    *temp = NULL;
    --list->number_of_nodes;
}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit better: It's a beginner!

Comment: @U.Windl: I think he's abandoned the question; else he'd ask for clarification or do something with it.

Comment: I was hoping someone more powerful could change the title, to help other users finding relevant questions. Too many titles are quite poor...